# Has anyone found polynomial algorithm on Hamiltonian cycle isomorphism?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, time-complexity

As the title says, has anyone found a polynomial time algorithm for checking whether two graphs having a Hamiltonian cycle are isomorphic? Is this problem NP-complete?

Comment: Definitely No, for Directed graphs at least. Because the Best Algorithm for Tournament isomorphism takes $O(n^{\log{n}})$. And Tournaments are the graphs with Hamiltonian paths. Refer to http://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/iui.inst.190/Mitarbeiter/wagner/TourIsoLB030907.pdf

Comment: @rizwanhudda Thank you very much. May I ask you one more question? Is this problem NP-complete?

Comment: Also, what about cycles?

Comment: I don't know any results about hamiltonian cycle. But, this problem can't be NP-Complete as it is a special case of Graph Isomorphism. And Graph Isomorphism isn't known to be NP-Complete.

Comment: As rizwanhudda said, this problem is a special case of the graph isomorphism problem and therefore it is _not known to be_ NP-complete.  We cannot say “this problem can’t be NP-complete” because of that, because the graph isomorphism problem might be NP-complete.  However, many complexity theorists believe that the graph isomorphism problem is not NP-complete (and therefore they will believe that your problem is not NP-complete, either) because the NP-completeness of the graph isomorphism problem would contradict the conjecture called “the polynomial hierarchy does not collapse.”

Comment: I feel that it should be difficult to show that the GI can be reduced to this problem, something like adding enough new vertices and connecting each of them to all of the original vertices and some additional structure to make sure the new vertices are mapped to new vertices might work.

Answer (score 7):

*What follows is taken from [Tsuyoshi Ito](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/568/tsuyoshi-ito)'s comment.*

As [rizwanhudda said](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/has-anyone-found-polynomial-algorithm-on-hamiltonian-cycle-isomorphism/4954#comment6444_2383), this problem is a special case of the graph isomorphism problem and therefore it is not known to be NP-complete. We cannot say “this problem can’t be NP-complete” because of that, because the graph isomorphism problem might be NP-complete. However, many complexity theorists believe that the graph isomorphism problem is not NP-complete (and therefore they will believe that your problem is not NP-complete, either) because the NP-completeness of the graph isomorphism problem would contradict the conjecture called “the polynomial hierarchy does not collapse.”

Comment: Please do not feel obligated to mark an answer as a community wiki just because it is a copy of my comment, in case you or anyone else feels so.

Comment: Well, I think this answer should be updated now that GI is known to be quasi-polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by Kaveh, perhaps this is a reduction that can prove that the class of graphs with an Hamiltonian cycle is GI-complete.

Given two graphs $G_1 = (V_1,E_1)$ and $G_2 = (V_2,E_2)$, $|V_1| = |V_2|=n$, expand $G_1$ with a complete graph $K_{2n}$ labeling its nodes in pairs $(a_i, b_i)$; then for each vertex $u_i \in |V_1|$ add two edges $(a_i,u_i)$ and $(u_i,b_i)$ that connect $G_1$ to the $K_{2n}$. Expand $G_2$ in the same way.

By construction the two expanded graphs $G'_1$ and $G'_2$ have an Hamiltonian cycle $(a_1 u_1 b_1 a_2 u_2 b_2 ... a_n u_n b_n a_1)$ and the original graphs are isomorphic iff $G'_1$ and $G'_2$ are isomorphic. Informally: in $G'_1$ and $G'_2$ the added nodes cannot "interfere" with the original isomorphism because their degree is greater than $\max(\text{deg}(u_i))$